# Middleware does not redirect to page on success of auth attempt.Using laravel 5.2 and Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

This in my routes

```
Route::post('companyLogin','Auth\AuthController@companyLogin');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Route::get('dashboard',['uses' => 'PageController@dashboard' ,  'as' => 'dashboard']);

});
```

This is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;

use Validator;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use View;

class AuthController extends Controller

{

 public function companyLogin()

    {

      $userdata = array(

            'email' => Input::get('email'),

            'password'  =>Input::get('password'));

       $isAuth = Auth::attempt($userdata);

        if($isAuth)
        {

           return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); 

        } else {        

           return view('login');

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: is it going to login page again

Comment: yeah, it is going back to login

Answer (score 0):

May be your credentials are wrong.

```
->i mean did you bcrypted the password and saved in the database.
->if you not bcrypted the password,then you must bcrypt the password and save in database.
->Auth::attemptbcrypt the password and then checks
```

example:

```
$userdata = array(

            'email' => 'yahoo@gmail.com',

            'password'  =>'yahoo';

       $isAuth = Auth::attempt($userdata);
```

Auth::attempt bcrypts the yahoo password and checks in database and returns false so it redirecting to login